# Aplicación Spring Boot se apaga cuando cierro la consola del servidor

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu, servidor, maven

Estoy teniendo un problema que la verdad que no tengo ni idea de como solucionar.
Tengo una aplicación de Java desarrollada con Spring Boot. El despliegue esta echo sobre un server cloud de Don Web que corre un Ubuntu 20.04 con Tomcat 10. Logro levantar la aplicación con el comando `java -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Hasta acá todo funciona perfecto, el problema viene cuando cierro la consola con la que me conecto al hosting vía ssh porque cuando la cierro también se cae la aplicación. No se como podre hacer para que la aplicación sigua a pesar de esto.
Estoy usando Spring Boot 2.7.5, Java 11 y Maven 3.6.2.
Alguna idea de como resolverlo??

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto ejecutando `nohub java -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &` Básicamente este comando permite que la aplicación se ejecute en segundo plano.